# How to duplicate monitor in lxpanel?

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, desktop

When I boot Raspberry pi 4b without a desktop (no matter buster or bullseye), the image is duplicated on two displays. If I boot the operating system with a desktop, then the displays show an extended picture. How can I load the Raspbian desktop on two displays with duplication? So that the desktop on the displays is shown the same.

Comment: Several options. e.g. use the display config utility and drag & drop 1 display on top of the other

Comment: @Dirk if you have time to write a full answer or provide a link to a tutorial on how to do this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in console or in script:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --same-as HDMI-1
```